# Django pickle object saved for calculations on request

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, request, pickle

I am making a small demo django application where there are some calculations for which I need to retrieve a complex object. I have saved the object to a file using Pickle. Now I want to keep the object in memory so that it is not retrieved for every request. Where can I load the object so that it remains there and is available for any request. There are some parameters passed with requests that are needed for calculation. The object is not related to Models.

Answer (score 0):

Consider utilizing a [caching backend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/). It's intended for this exact purpose, and offers the desired persistence you're looking for. A tempting alternative might be a global variable established in some python file, however its value will not necessarily be consistent between requests when changes are made to it.

The ideal production caching solution would utilize a caching server like [Memcached](https://memcached.org/) or [Redis](https://redis.io/), providing the best performance. However these solutions will require installation and (the level of which depending on your needs) maintenance since they are server software, similar to your database or web server.

For a demo application the database caching backend might be the best, since it has no significant additional requirements, beyond whatever database you're already using for the application.